# How to show Windows keyboard on OS Windows touchscreen - Flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I am building a desktop app with Flutter and I would like to show the touchscreen keyboard of Windows when I need it, for example in a `TextFormField`.
Because this desktop app will be installed on HMI panels where Windows is installed but there is no physical keyboard.
Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution ? If yes, do you have the same problem as I have: when I hide the keyboard and change page with Navigator.push() (or maybe after a setState((){})) or whatever, the keyboard appears by himself even if there is no TextFormField()